# How can I make a screen width condition to a script tag on a shopify liquid?

Tags: shopify, screen, liquid

How can I create a condition to to a script tag (the first script tag )
The condition is: Keep the line if screen width > 760px
Else: delete this script tag ?

The language is liquid (Shopify)

I know that liquid is a backend so I have no access to the screen width.
I know that I could do it width JS and the script tag is on JS.

```
{% if product.media.size > 0 %}
  <script src="{{ 'product-modal.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
  <script src="{{ 'media-gallery.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
{% endif %}
```